# Is there a way to use a generic IR receiver with a MCE remote in Vista/7 Media Center

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center, remote-control, infrared

I have a MCE remote from long ago (shipped with an MCE 2005), but i cannot find the IR receiver.
I now have Win7 and a generic usb IR receiver i picked up a fry's.
Is there a way to make my old mce remote work with this 'generic' usb ir receiver?
If I buy a logitech harmoney remote, will it be able to control media center via my generic IR receiver or do I need to buy a MCE IR receiver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the generic IR receiver as long it's compatible with [EventGhost](http://www.eventghost.org/) and teach it to use the new remote commands to send them as keystrokes to Windows (and eventually to MCE itself).

Here is a list of all the keyboard shortcuts that MCE accepts: [Windows Media Center keyboard shortcuts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Windows-Media-Center-keyboard-shortcuts).

The only problem I've noticed is that MCE doesn't provide a keyboard shortcut to open the on-screen keyboard, so prepare to miss that...

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A more in-depth answer is here:
https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/human_errors-guide-to-usb-ir-receivers-and-media-centre-remotes.98630/

Outside of Saxtus's suggestions, more generic compatibility can be achieved by buying specific IR receivers, which are listed on the page above, along with other user information.